# psql \watch implementation for MariaDB? Repeatedly execute the current query

Tags: mysql, mariadb, client

Quote from current [Postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)

> `\watch [ seconds ]` 
>   Repeatedly execute the current query buffer (as \g
>   does) until interrupted or the query fails. Wait the specified number
>   of seconds (default 2) between executions. Each query result is
>   displayed with a header that includes the \pset title string (if any),
>   the time as of query start, and the delay interval.

Is there some similar functionality for MariaDB or MySQL?

For example this statement I wish to repeat every 2 seconds. In Linux it's the `watch` command

```
NAME
       watch - execute a program periodically, showing output fullscreen
```

run statement till state changes.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE state = retry
```

Comment: No.  What query were you wanting to repeat?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you want, but this shell command might suffice:

```
$ mysql ... -e "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE state = retry"
```